# stuck at ld: cannot find -llua

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile some sources with Dev-Cpp v2 but the compiler stucked at 
cannot find -llua
also here's my Linker
-llua
-llibxml2
-lwsock32
-llibboost_thread-mgw-mt-1_33_1
-lgmp

i tried to remove -llua but it said cannot find -llibboost_thread-mgw-mt-1_33_1

here is the source file it's free, if it's can help more
https://github.com/hrsantiago/magebomb/

here's the compile log:--

Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "C:\Users\Amr\Desktop\magebomb-master\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "C:\Users\Amr\Desktop\magebomb-master\Makefile.win" all
windres.exe -i Mage_Bomb_private.rc --input-format=rc -o Source/Obj/Mage_Bomb_private.res -O coff

g++.exe Source/Obj/main.o Source/Obj/Config.o Source/Obj/XML.o Source/Obj/Login.o Source/Obj/RSA.o Source/Obj/Position.o Source/Obj/NetworkMessage.o Source/Obj/Mage_Bomb_private.res -o "magebomb.exe" -L"C:/Users/Amr/Desktop/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/lib" -llua -llibxml2 -lwsock32 -llibboost_thread-mgw-mt-1_33_1 -lgmp  -s

ld: cannot find -llua

make.exe: *** [magebomb.exe] Error 1

Execution terminated

Edit:- i replaced -llua with -llua5.1
stucked at cannot find -llibboost_thread-mgw-mt-1_33_1

Comment: have you downloaded or built these libraries?

Comment: "How do I use this <random program I found on the internet>?" is not, in my opinion, a programming question.

Comment: i replaced -llua with -llua5.1 stucked at cannot find -llibboost_thread-mgw-mt-1_33_1 i don't know what -llibboost_thread-mgw-mt-1_33_1 called i think i have already some libaries

Comment: i just want to compile it :/

Comment: -llua means you should have liblua.so somewhere in your library path (either standard like /usr/lib) or additional specifiedwith -L key to g++. So you have to find a source from where this library is taken and build it or install it via your packet manager.

Comment: Since you've now successfully found the `lua` lib, rename the question.
Replace `-llibboost_thread-mgw-mt-1_33_1` with `-lboost_thread-mgw-mt-1_33_1` and see if that helps.